# M nearest points to centroid in K-Means clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, centroid

I have implemented a function to find **the nearest** data point to each centroid calculated after running the K-Means clustering algorithm. I wanted to know if there's a `sklearn` function that allows me to find the **M** nearest points to each of the centroids.

Answer (score 1):

After running K-means, we can use [sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn-neighbors-nearestneighbors) to fit our dataset. We can then query the Nearest Neighbor model with our K-means centroids to retrieve the neighbors. Like this:

```py
# Copyright 2024 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

# random dense embeddings for 100 points with 10 dimensions.
dataset = np.random.rand(100,10)

# fit K-means with 3 clusters on our dataset.
kme = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kme.fit(dataset)

# we should have 3 vectors for 3 centroids.
print(kme.cluster_centers_.shape) # (3, 10)

# initialize NearestNeighbor with 5 neighbors and fit our dataset.
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, metric='cosine')
knn.fit(dataset)

# Use the model to query the centroids' neighbors.
distances, indices = knn.kneighbors(kme.cluster_centers_)

for centroid, distance_from_centroid, index in zip(kme.cluster_centers_, distances, indices):
  print(centroid, distance_from_centroid, index)
```

The last loop will output 3 lines. Each one resembles the vector of a centroid along with 5 distances and indices of its closest neighbors.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you want to check out the following tutorial from sklearn : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html

The classsklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors finds it for you: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors

Comment: eventhough this answer does not exactly answer the question, the point he makes is valid. You can use `sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors` and use `kneighbors` function to find the nearest neighbours of the cluster centroids.